# How can I add app images to the assets catalog for both the iPad and iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, assets, uiimageasset

In Xcode 7.2 *(Beta 4)* there isn't a slot for an iPad Pro in the image asset catalog *(xcassets folder)*. If I select an image (not app icon) in the Xcode assets there is no slot for iPad Pro. There is just a 1x slot and a 2x slot when iPad is selected as the device. Since the iPad Pro is a higher resolution I would have thought they would have needed to add an iPad Pro slot.

Am I missing something here?

My thought was that I could build the UI to be based on an image's ***intrinsic size*** so that a particular image and its surrounding UI elements would **appear to be the same size** for both the iPad Pro and previous iPad models.

Comment: It's a higher resolution but i believe it uses the same size of icons as iPad measured in points. Higher res just means that there is more pixel density or pixels/point, So you can put a higher resolution photo but it would still be same size on ipad vs ipad pro

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey if this is the case then there is probably no way to build a layout (using constraints in the storyboard) based on intrinsic content size and have the images appear to be the same size. :-(

Comment: Can you update Xcode? It may not be supported in 7.2 and now that we have 8.0 betas I'm curious if this has been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iPad Pro uses 2x assets even though its resolution is the highest in the iPad family (2732x2048).  The only iPad Pro specific setting in an asset catalog right now is for the AppIcon image set:

[image: iPad Pro App Icon]

Additionally, the LaunchImage image set does not support the iPad Pro either, as Apple is dropping support of launch images in favor of Launch Storyboards.  See [rdar://22915712](https://openradar.appspot.com/22915712) for more information.